# How can I solve this "is not a valid XPath expression"

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to select a country from the country dropDown.

```
List<WebElement> countryDropDown = driver.findElements(By.xpath(("(//div[@class='uk-dropdown uk-open uk-dropdown-bottom-center']//li")));
WebdriverHelper.selectOptionFromDropDown(countryDropDown, "Spain");
```

The dropdown opens, the list is displayed, then I receive this message:

> Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '(//div[@class='uk-dropdown uk-open uk-dropdown-bottom-center']//li' is not a valid XPath expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are redundant parenthesis there.
Instead of

```java
List<WebElement> countryDropDown = driver.findElements(By.xpath(("(//div[@class='uk-dropdown uk-open uk-dropdown-bottom-center']//li")));
```

Try this:

```java
List<WebElement> countryDropDown = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='uk-dropdown uk-open uk-dropdown-bottom-center']//li"));
```